# How to iterate over all the inner array elements and make modification to the original multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, key-value

I'm relatively a newbie to PHP arrays and I've a big challenging task in front of me, so please understand my situation.

I've a multidimensional array titled `$events` as follows :

```
//Output of print_r($events);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 2
                    [event_id] => 237
                    [formatted_start_time] => 1443052800
                    [formatted_end_time] => 1443052800
                    [event_group_date] => 24 Sep, Thursday 2015
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [event_id] => 295
                    [formatted_start_time] => 1443070800
                    [formatted_end_time] => 1443070800
                    [event_group_date] => 24 Sep, Thursday 2015
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [event_id] => 294
                    [formatted_start_time] => 1443099600
                    [formatted_end_time] => 1443099600
                    [event_group_date] => 24 Sep, Thursday 2015
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [event_id] => 297
                    [formatted_start_time] => 1443101100
                    [formatted_end_time] => 1443101100
                    [event_group_date] => 24 Sep, Thursday 2015
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [event_id] => 296
                    [formatted_start_time] => 1443103200
                    [formatted_end_time] => 1443103200
                    [event_group_date] => 24 Sep, Thursday 2015
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [event_id] => 330
                    [formatted_start_time] => 1443118800
                    [formatted_end_time] => 1443122400
                    [event_group_date] => 24 Sep, Thursday 2015
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [event_id] => 298
                    [formatted_start_time] => 1443124800
                    [formatted_end_time] => 1443124800
                    [event_group_date] => 24 Sep, Thursday 2015
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 2
                    [event_id] => 332
                    [formatted_start_time] => 1443189600
                    [formatted_end_time] => 1443193200
                    [event_group_date] => 25 Sep, Friday 2015
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 
                    [event_id] => 239
                    [formatted_start_time] => 1443571200
                    [formatted_end_time] => 1443571200
                    [event_group_date] => 30 Sep, Wednesday 2015
                )

        )

)
```

Now I want to iterate over each of the events from above array, pass the respective `event_id` in each iteration to a function, receive the array output returned by the function, do some conditional checking and based on a condition result either keep or remove that particular event element in above array.

For example, in one iteration I've to pass `event_id` 332 to a function as follows :

```
$aEventInvites = getInvites(332); //For understanding purpose only hard coded event_id is passed, actually it should be passed dynamically  during each iteration.
```

After executing above statement I receive following result:

```
    //Output of print_r($aEventInvites);
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [invite_id] => 698
                    [event_id] => 332
                    [type_id] => 0
                    [rsvp_id] => 0
                    [user_id] => 970
                    [invited_user_id] => 970
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [invite_id] => 697
                    [event_id] => 332
                    [type_id] => 0
                    [rsvp_id] => 0
                    [user_id] => 244
                    [invited_user_id] => 244
                )

        )

)
```

Note : For each `event_id` from the array `$events` the function `getInvites()` should get call.

Now let's talk about condition. Before that consider below statement :

```
$looged_in_user_id = 244;
```

The final array `$events` I want which would only contain elements satisfying either of the following conditions :

1. The elements from array `$events` should be kept as it is which contains some value in the field `rsvp_id`(it should not be blank)
2. The elements from array `$events` should be kept as it is whose event iteration output satisfies following condition:

   - The `invited_user_id` should be same as `$logged_in_user_id` and `event_id` should be present in an array `$aEventInvites`.

For example in case of iteration for `event_id = 332`, the array `$aEventInvites` contains both these things as follows :

```
Array
                    (
                        [invite_id] => 697
                        [event_id] => 332
                        [type_id] => 0
                        [rsvp_id] => 0
                        [user_id] => 244
                        [invited_user_id] => 244
                    )
```

So, in such case do nothing to the element from the array `$events` of `event_id = 332`.

In short I want final `$events` array in exactly following form :

```
//Final required output of print_r($events);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 2
                    [event_id] => 237
                    [formatted_start_time] => 1443052800
                    [formatted_end_time] => 1443052800
                    [event_group_date] => 24 Sep, Thursday 2015
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 1
                    [event_id] => 330
                    [formatted_start_time] => 1443118800
                    [formatted_end_time] => 1443122400
                    [event_group_date] => 24 Sep, Thursday 2015
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rsvp_id] => 2
                    [event_id] => 332
                    [formatted_start_time] => 1443189600
                    [formatted_end_time] => 1443193200
                    [event_group_date] => 25 Sep, Friday 2015
                )

        )

)
```

**Note : The array index should be modified starting from 0 onwards. Like in above expected output.**

Someone please help me in achieving this task.
Please feel free to ask any of the doubt you have regarding the required output.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got the conditions right, atleast I get the same result you are expecting with the given informations:

```
function process(array $events, $logged_in_user_id) {
$newEvents = [];

foreach ($events as $i => $key) {
    if (is_array($key) && !isset($key["event_id"])) {
        foreach ($key as $index => $event) {
            if (is_array($event) && isset($event["event_id"])) {
                $conditions = false;
                if (!isset($event["rsvp_id"])) {
                    $aEventInvites = getInvites($event["event_id"]);

                    // try to match
                    foreach ($aEventInvites as $aeiKey => $aeiValue) {
                        if (is_array($aeiValue)) {
                            foreach ($aeiValue as $invites) {
                                if (isset($invites["invited_user_id"]) && isset($invites["event_id"])) {
                                    if (
                                           $invites["invited_user_id"] == $logged_in_user_id
                                        && $invites["event_id"]        == $event["event_id"]
                                    ) {
                                        $conditions = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $conditions = true;
                }

                if ($conditions) {
                    $newEvents[] = $event;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return $newEvents;
}
```

You could make the use of `continue;` instead of a bool `$conditions` variable inside the last loop. In general, if you are able to modify the output of `getInvites($event_id)` I would recommend you to change the resulting array into an assoc array (meaning instead of number indexes use string indexes like "num_of_invitees" and "invitees") you could then access these fields directly without iterating over the result (with leads to a little more performance).

It's not a beatiful solution but it is atleast a working one. Have fun.

Edit: Forgot the fiddle link: http://ideone.com/XpNTRn